# find repeated substring in a string

Tags: c#

I have a substring

```
string subString = "ABC";
```

Every time all three chars appears in a input, you get one point

for example, if input is:

`"AABKM"` = 0 points 
`"AAKLMBDC"` = 1 point 
`"ABCC"` = 1 point because all three occurs once   
`"AAZBBCC"` = 2 points because ABC is repeated twice; 
etc..

The only solution I could come up with is

```
Regex.Matches(input, "[ABC]").Count
```

But does not give me what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: I think this will be hard with a single liner. It might be best to just figure out the algorithmi, and afterwards determine if it can be solved with regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a ternary operation, where first we determine that all the characters are present in the string (else we return `0`), and then select only those characters, group by each character, and return the minimum count from the groups:

For example:

```
string subString = "ABC";
var inputStrings = new[] {"AABKM", "AAKLMBDC", "ABCC", "AAZBBCC"};

foreach (var input in inputStrings)
{
    var result = subString.All(input.Contains)
        ? input
            .Where(subString.Contains)
            .GroupBy(c => c)
            .Min(g => g.Count())
        : 0;

    Console.WriteLine($"{input}: {result}");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is better

Answer (score 1):

It could be done with a single line, using Linq. However I am not very confident that this could be a good solution

```
string subString = "ABC"; 
string input = "AAZBBBCCC";

var arr = input.ToCharArray()
               .Where(x => subString.Contains(x))
               .GroupBy(x => x)
               .OrderBy(a => a.Count())
               .First()
               .Count();
```

The result is 2 because the letter A is present only two times.

Let's try to explain the linq expression.
First transform the input string in a sequence of chars, then take only the chars that are contained in the substring. Now group these chars and order them according the the number of occurrences. At this point take the first group and read the count of chars in that group.

Let's see if someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
 string subString = "ABC";
        var input = new[] { "AABKM", "AAKLMBDC", "ABCC", "AAZBBCC" };

        foreach (var item in input)
        {
            List<int> a = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < subString.Length; i++)
            {
                a.Add(Regex.Matches(item, subString.ToList()[i].ToString()).Count);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{item} : {a.Min()}");
        }
```

Comment: Nice! You don't need the `.ToList()`, though - strings implement `IEnumerable<char>`.